# Creating a generic class and parameter in Java

Tags: java, android, generics

I have a general sendRequest() method that I use to get a json result back from the server. I'm parsing the result in an instance of the callback right now, but instead I'd much rather just pass in a type to the sendRequest() method so I can parse and handle exceptions before the callback. How can I do this? I've included the relevant code and some comments below.

```
public void sendRequest(int method, String url, final RequestListener listener) {
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(method, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    listener.gotResponse(response, null);

                    // Instead of parsing this into a user object, I'd like to parse it into
                    // a type that I pass into the sendRequest() method.
                    try {
                        User user = User.parseJson(new JSONObject(response));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all please note that out of the box you have `JsonObjectRequest` which will convert the response directly into a `JSONObject` which seems to be better than `StringRequest` in your case, but as you want to go a little bit further I would propose to create a [custom request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html) based on a generic unmarshaller.

```
public interface JsonUnmarshaller<T> {
    T parse(JSONObject object) throws JSONException;
}
```

The custom request could be something like this:

```
public class JSONRequest extends Request<T> {
    private final Listener<T> mListener;
    private final JsonUnmarshaller<T> unmarshaller;

    public JSONRequest(int method, String url, Listener<T> listener,
        ErrorListener errorListener, JsonUnmarshaller<T> unmarshaller) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        mListener = listener;
        this.unmarshaller = unmarshaller;
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }
    @Override
    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        String parsed;
        try {
            parsed = new String(
                response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers)
            );
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            parsed = new String(response.data);
        }
        try {
            return Response.success(
                unmarshaller.parse(new JSONObject(parsed)), 
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response)
            );
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }
}
```

Then your method would be:

```
public <T> void sendRequest(int method, String url, final RequestListener 
                            listener, JsonUnmarshaller<T> unmarshaller) {
    JSONRequest postRequest = new JSONRequest(...
```

Comment: I feel silly for failing to read the docs, the example they had on that page was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a little something for you here, I think you will be able to apply this to your example:

```java
import java.util.*;
public class Cat{
    public static void main(String... args){
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        cat.send(Dog.class);
        cat.send(Mouse.class);
    }

    public <T extends Parseable> void send(Class<T> clazz){
        try{
            T t = clazz.newInstance();
            t.parse();
        } catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}

interface Parseable{
    void parse();
}

class Dog implements Parseable{
    public void parse(){
        System.out.println("Dog parse");
    }
}

class Mouse implements Parseable{
    public void parse(){
        System.out.println("Mouse parse");
    }
}
```

Your method is static so you probably can just do `T.parseJson()`. Not sure if there won't be any problems with transfering generic type to anonymous listener, but I hope it will work.